# How to switch from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 with ng2-bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am using [ng2-bootstrap](http://valor-software.github.io/ng2-bootstrap/index-bs4.html) for an Angular 2 project.

This package supports both Bootstrap 3 and 4. After I install it, it uses Bootstrap 3 by default. I didn't find any information about switching.

How can I switch from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4? Should I write something in the file `tsconfig.json`?

Thank you!

Comment: It is completely bizarre that they say 'it plays well with v3 and v4' but then there's absolutely nothing to show how to switch in the docs :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the theme to bootstrap4

```
import {Ng2BootstrapConfig, Ng2BootstrapTheme} from '../ng2-bootstrap';    

Ng2BootstrapConfig.theme = Ng2BootstrapTheme.BS4;
```

**Note:** The above code should be used before your main component. The same place where you will use angular2's `enableProdMode();`

Comment: Thanks, but it shows `Module '"ng2-bootstrap"' has no exported member 'Ng2BootstrapConfig'.` `Module '"ng2-bootstrap"' has no exported member 'Ng2BootstrapTheme'.`

Comment: Make sure you are referencing it properly,  they are being exported as seen here https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/master/components/ng2-bootstrap-config.ts

Comment: Thank you, @Vamsi. Sorry for late reply. My question is about Angular2, so your answer is a correct answer. However, I actually created a angular2-meteor project. I think the problem is `Ng2BootstrapConfig` and `Ng2BootstrapTheme` are not exported in the **ng2-bootstrap.d.ts** file. So I created an issue, https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/114

Comment: Just before defining your main app component, The same place where you will use angular2's `enableProdMode();`

Answer (score 4):

Actually Vamsi's answer isn't working for me in the current version. I looked through the source code and this does work:

Put this in the top of your `<head>` in the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // temporary hack for enable bootstrap 4
    window.__theme = 'bs4';
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you place the code? 
You should place the code before your app's main component

Comment: You can se here, attaching `window.__theme` doesn't do anything, they are using that value to change `Ng2BootstrapConfig.theme` based on that value

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/demo/index.ts#L26

Comment: This solution worked for me where @Vamsi's did not. Using RC.3 with Webpack Starter Kit.

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

uninstall boostrap package

`npm uninstall --save bootstrap`

install boostrap 4 package

`npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5`

As ng2-boostrap works with both packages, it simply detect the bootstrap package installed and that's all. It's working for me.